# Add users to SP Group

Tags: 2010, powershell, spuser

I am using following PS script to add users from a text file. Some of the users in the text file are inactive or gone (basically can't be resolved). The error message from the catch block is executed for all the users. If invalid user then it should display $spUser does not exists. Can anyone see what am I doing incorrect here? Just wanted to mention that valid AD users are getting added. EnsureUser is throwing exception when user not found in AD.

```
$webUrl = "http://server"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$fileWithPath = "N:\Staging\Users.txt"
$content = Get-Content $fileWithPath
$spGroup = "Northwest Region Sales"
$rd="Read"

foreach($user in $content)
{    
    try
    {
        $spUser = $web.EnsureUser($user)
        if($spUser -ne $null)
        {
        Write-Host $spuser
            Write-Host "Adding " $spUser
            $web.SiteGroups[$spGroup].AddUser($spUser)
            Write-Host $user  " User added to the group successfully"
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host $spUser " does not exists"
    }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Error occured on " $user
    } 
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code - permission issue, group doesn't exist? Try to get exception message by using $_ in catch block : [Trap and Try/Catch](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/09/14/trap-and-try-catch.aspx).

Comment: Also try adding `$spGroup = $web.SiteGroups[$spGroup]` and `Write-Host $spGroup` to see if group is found

Comment: Actually, the valid users are being added to the SPGroup. It's only when a user is not found (due to deletion from AD or set to Inactive).

Comment: I added the extra $_ to the catch block. I see this error. I thought EnsureUser will return a boolen (1/0 or true/false). I see this error for the bad users. Error occured on: Exception calling "EnsureUser" with "1" argument(s): "The specified user Domain\csantana could not be
found."

Comment: I don't get it. `EnsureUser` throws exception if user is not found. If exception is thrown then user don't exist so you write 'does not exist' and foreach loop will continue. You can remove if statement because it is useless.

Comment: @VedranRasol: Yes sir, you are correct. The EnsureUser could have been writen better by MS SP team. but oh well, I am with you if statement can go away and script will continue to add the remainder of the users from the text file. Thanks for looking into this. I found this article where he talks about the flow in EnsureUser method. http://www.informationworker.co.za/blogs/mirror/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1407

Comment: Could one of you guys summarize these comments into an answer? That way we can accept it.

Comment: I agree : `EnsureUser` could return null if no user is found. Using try catch block to handle this is basically wrong approach but sadly it is the only one. Checking AD for users (your link) is IMO overkill - but of course it depends on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize comments.

[SpWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) method will throw an exception if user account doesn't exist in Active Directory or if it is disabled.

Code provided in question could look like this (in foreach loop):

```
try
{
    $spUser = $web.EnsureUser($user)

    Write-Host "Adding " $spUser
    $web.SiteGroups[$spGroup].AddUser($spUser)
    Write-Host $user  " User added to the group successfully"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $spUser " does not exists"
}
```

Using try catch block is not the best option but in this case it is the only option.

Some more details with C# example on how to check AD for user can be found here:

- [Checking if a User Account is Enabled in Active Directory](http://www.informationworker.co.za/blogs/mirror/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1407)